# Div table showing disturbed cells for ColSpan

Tags: html, css

I am trying to convert following HTML table to DIV table.

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="5"></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried to covert it in DIV,

But when I am putting image in first column its disturbing all rows size.

Please check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiransajanikar/he7pb45a/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that problem, just in your `.cell` class add this `vertical-align: top;`
Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he7pb45a/2/), i have edited your code